# Colocar o valor de uma hql em uma var

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Eu necessito fazer com que minhas duas tabelas trabalhem juntas, onde a `Abastecimento` pegue o Nome do Produto(`NomeProdutoId`), da tabela `Compra`, consegui fazer ele pegar o Nome do Produto, mas queria que junto me trouxesse o Valor daquele Produto, e cadastrar na tabela `Abastecimento`, um exemplo seria aqueles formulários cadastrais, onde você informa o seu Estado e logo abaixo trás somente cidades daquele estado.

Porém no meu queria o valor, e o ultimo valor registrado, daquele produto.

Essa parte foi um tentativa onde em outro formulário usava um esquema para me trazer um veiculo e então compara o KM.

Se necessita alterar a query e o controller eu consigo, ou então colocar chave estrangeira, não ha problema.

Model Compra:

```
public class Compra
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Tipo { get; set; }
        public virtual float VlrUnit { get; set; }
        public virtual float VlrTotal { get; set; }
        public virtual int Quant { get; set; }
        public virtual string NomeProduto { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime DtCompra { get; set; }
        public virtual Fornecedores Nome { get; set; }
    }
```

Model Abastecimento:

```
public class Abastecimento
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public virtual int Litro { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DtAbastecido { get; set; }
    public virtual float VlrUnit { get; set; }
    public virtual int Km { get; set; }
    public virtual float TotalGasto { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Autor { get; set; }
    public virtual Compra NomeProduto { get; set; }
    public virtual Veiculo NumCarro { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Adiciona(AbastecimentoModel viewModel)
    {
        var Produto = ckm.ConsultaProduto(viewModel.NomeProdutoId);

        /*Aqui na verdade é um teste, mas o objetivo dele seria para pegar os valores que tem na tabela compra, e então utilizar na variavel Valor, para ordernar*/
        var teste = ckm.ConsultaValor(compra.VlrUnit);

        var Valor = Produto.OrderByDescending(a => teste).Last();

        viewModel.TotalGasto = viewModel.Litro * viewModel.VlrUnitId;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Abastecimento abastecimento = viewModel.CriaAbastecimento();
            dao.Adiciona(abastecimento);
            //return View();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        { 
            ViewBag.Compra = compraDAO.Lista();
            ViewBag.Usuarios = usuarioDAO.Lista();
            ViewBag.Veiculo = veiculoDAO.Lista();
            return View("Form",viewModel);
        }

    }
```

Query:

```
public IList<Compra> ConsultaValor(float VlrUnit)
    {
        string hql = "SELECT c FROM Compra c";
        IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
        return query.List<Compra>();
    }
```

Tabela Compra:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: "_o problema que retorna valor, zero ou então valor de uma outra variavel_". Tem como explicar um pouco melhor? Isso tá meio confuso.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Não entendo tanto de c# com o nhibernate, mas em outro formulario, consegui utilizar desse modo, onde o select pegava todas as informaçoes e pelo controller conseguiria organizar

Comment: @LINQ não sei se melhorou, mas seria basicamente onde eu tento puxar o valor e ele não puxa, assim não registrando nada

Comment: Amigo, você ainda não sbe o que você realmente precisa, ou não sabe expor isso aqui. Não dar para elaborar uma resposta sem você posta suas classes , e dizer o que espera dos seus selects.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Acho que agora ficou mais claro, e os models foram postados para mostra onde tem chaves e qual a primary key

Comment: qual o relacionamento entre a tabela produto e compra ? poste a Produto também

Comment: Não existe a tabela `Produto`, o produto que eu digo, é quando se registra na tabela `Compra`, todo produto que existi e vai existir está na tabela `Compra`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente alterar seu método para;

```
public Compra ConsultaValor()
{
    return Session.Query<Compra>()
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.DtCompra)
                .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

E na chamada

```
var utimaCompra = ckm.ConsultaValor();

Abastecimento abastecimento = viewModel.CriaAbastecimento();

abastecimento.VlrUnit = utimaCompra.VlrUnit;
abastecimento.NomeProduto = utimaCompra.NomeProduto;
```

Comment: OK, e para que você usar o `a => teste` no order by ?  não seria um `Where(p => p.compra == teste.compra)` ? outra coisa ... o OrderByDescending` faz uma ordenação decrescente  e o .Last(); pegar o ultimo valor dessar ordenação, ou seja... seria o primeiro objeto sem ordenar.

Comment: Vamos por parte, o que realmente tem que ser retornado do seu método ConsultaValor ? qual parâmetro ele tem quer receber ? vai usar ele para que? Edite na sua resposta.....

Comment: Marco, o código deu certo, mas é que ele ou está pegando o ultimo valor ou o primeiro, dependendo do jeito que eu coloco o `OrderBy`, não teria como fazer para ele pegar o valor de acordo com o produto selecionado?

Comment: Sim, você tem o id do produto ? se tive você pode passar como parametro para a sua consulta e usar o Where(x => x.idproduto == id) algo assim.

Comment: Tenho Id sim, vou implantar a linha no parâmetro.